# Python: check tab delimited file for a proper number of columns

Tags: python, file, input

Check to make sure that

a) each line is 4 columns long

b) make sure that it doesn't fail if theres a new line ('\n') at the end of the program

```
def ask_for_filename():
    filename=raw_input("Please enter file name: ")
    return filename

def read_data(filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
           data = f.readlines()

        i = 0
        for line in data:
            lineContains = line.split('\t')
            lineLength = len(lineContains)  #calculate elements


            i = i+1

            if lineLength < 3 and i < len(data):        
                print "File is invalid format."

        f.close()
        return data
```

Can you please correct where I have the problem as this part of the code does not work.

```
        i = 0
        for line in data:
            lineContains = line.split('\t')
            lineLength = len(lineContains)  #calculate elements


            i = i+1

            if lineLength < 3 and i < len(data):        
                print "File is invalid format."
```

Sample file contents:

**Complete file:**

```
AUTHOR(S)   YEAR    TITLE   JOURNAL/CONFERENCE

Accot;Zhai  2001    Scale effects in steering law tasks Proc. ACM CHI

Acredolo    1977    Developmental Changes in the Ability to Coordinate Perspectives of a Large-Scale Space  Developmental Psychology

Aginsky;Harris;Rensink;Beusmans 1997    Two strategies for learning a route in a driving simulator  Journal of Environmental Psychology
```

**Incomplete file (aforementioned code is for these kind of files):**

```
AUTHOR(S)   YEAR    TITLE   JOURNAL/CONFERENCE

Accot;Zhai  2001    Scale effects in steering law tasks Proc. ACM CHI

Acredolo    Developmental Changes in the Ability to Coordinate Perspectives of a Large-Scale Space  Developmental Psychology

Aginsky;Harris;Rensink;Beusmans 1997    Two strategies for learning a route in a driving simulator  Journal of Environmental Psychology

Agrawala;Beers;Frohlich;Hanrahan;McDowall;Bolas 1997    The two-user responsive workbench: Support for collaboration through individual views of a shared space Proc. ACM SIGGRAPH

Ahmadabadi;Eiji 1996    Cooperation strategy for a group of object lifting robots   Proc. of IROS
```

Comment: Does it give you any error?What do you get? what you want to check with `if lineLength < 2 and i < len(data)`

Comment: I guess you should check for `lineLength!=4`

Comment: Can we get about 5 lines of sample data as expected input?

Comment: @Droogans Thanks, I am going to update the file.

Comment: @AlButter for it to be 4 columns you should check it with lineLength!=4`

Comment: The reason this "does not influence the rest of the program in any way" is that you haven't written any code that modifies `data` or changes the flow of execution; all that you've written is a `print` statement. If you want it to abort on invalid data, `raise` instead of `print`ing. If you want it to skip invalid data, either remove bad lines from `data` or (better) build a copy of `data` with only the good lines, and return that.

Comment: As a side note… There is almost never a good reason to call `readlines()`, and there are a lot of good reasons not to. If your tutor has recommended it to you, you may want to find a tutor who's not still writing Python 1.6.

Comment: @abarnert I can't really understand what you mean. Can you please show  a practical example/solution?

Comment: @AlButter: Which comment are you replying to? Until you tell us _in what way_ you want the code to influence the rest of the program, it's very hard to show you how to make it influence the rest of the program…

Comment: As a general rule at stackoverflow, show us what you've tried first, with sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @woozyking I have just deleted my code, because none of the answers were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You complain that your code "does not influence the rest of the program in any way".

Since there is nothing inside the relevant code that modifies any data or changes any control flow, of course it doesn't influence the rest of the program. So `read_data` always returns all of the lines in the file, valid or invalid.

Since you didn't explain *how* you want it to influence the rest of the program, it's hard to show you how to do what you want… but I can show you how to do *something*.

For example, instead of returning all of the lines, let's return just the valid lines:

```
i = 0
result = []
for line in data:
    lineContains = line.split('\t')
    lineLength = len(lineContains)  #calculate elements

    i = i+1

    if lineLength < 3 and i < len(data):
        print "File is invalid format."
    else:
        result.append(line)

return result
```

Or, to raise an exception rather than returning anything:

```
i = 0
for line in data:
    lineContains = line.split('\t')
    lineLength = len(lineContains)  #calculate elements

    i = i+1

    if lineLength < 3 and i < len(data):
        raise ValueError("File is invalid format.")

return data
```

---

Meanwhile, there are some other problems with your code.

You should not call `f.close()` after using `f` in a `with` block. Usually you'll get lucky and it will be harmless, but "usually harmless and never helpful" is not the kind of code you want.

If you want to count all the lines in something, don't add an explicit `i = i+1` to your loop, just use `enumerate`.

Also, I'm not sure what the `i < len(data)` is supposed to do, since it will always be true. So I'll just leave that out. (Which means I could also leave `i` out entirely, since it's the only place you use it… but I'll leave it in, so I can show you `enumerate`.

There is almost never a good reason to call `readlines()`. A file is already an iterable full of lines, just like the list that `readlines` returns. All you've done is forced your code to be slower and take up more memory by reading in the whole file at once, instead of on demand.

So, here's the skipping-bad-lines version:

```
def read_data(filename):
    result = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            lineContains = line.split('\t')
            lineLength = len(lineContains)  #calculate elements
            if lineLength < 3:        
                print "File is invalid format."
            else:
                result.append(line)
    return result
```

Meanwhile, do you really want to print out a warning for every invalid line if there may be, say, 100000 of them? If not, you can make this simpler:

```
def read_data(filename):
    def bad_line(line):
        lineContains = line.split('\t')
        lineLength = len(lineContains)  #calculate elements
        return lineLength < 3
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [line for line in f if not bad_line(line)]
```

Comment: @AlButter: If you're sure that's what you want to do (quitting early with a success returncode is an odd way to signal an error…), you should be able to figure out how to replace the `raise` with a `sys.exit`, or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_data_valid(filename):
    data = open(filename).readlines()
    lines = [x.split('\t') for x in data]
    no_newlines = [line for line in lines if len(line) > 1]
    return all(len(line) == 4 for line in no_newlines)
```